# Laravel 6: Encryption using virgil/crypto error: Call to undefined function vscf_ctr_drbg_new_php

Tags: php, encryption, laravel-6, homestead

I'm trying to use https://github.com/VirgilSecurity/virgil-crypto-php to encrypt/decrypt data with public/private keys in Laravel homestead like this

```
composer require virgil/crypto

use Virgil\Crypto\VirgilCrypto;
// inside the function:
$crypto = new VirgilCrypto();
$receiverKeyPair = $crypto->generateKeyPair();
```

Then installed the SDK https://github.com/VirgilSecurity/virgil-sdk-php

```
composer require virgil/sdk
./vendor/virgil/crypto-wrapper/_extensions/setup.sh -all -vendor
```

And I can see these extensions `vsce_phe_php, vscf_foundation_php, vscp_pythia_php` after running `php -m` command but I get

```
Call to undefined function Virgil\CryptoWrapper\Foundation\vscf_ctr_drbg_new_php() {"exception":"[object] 
(Symfony\\Component\\Debug\\Exception\\FatalThrowableError(code: 0): Call to undefined function 
Virgil\\CryptoWrapper\\Foundation\\vscf_ctr_drbg_new_php() at 
/home/vagrant/code/my-project/vendor/virgil/crypto-wrapper/src/Foundation/CtrDrbg.php:63)
```

All the functions in this can't can't be found anywhere in the package how can I fix this?

Comment: What have you tried to resolve the problem? Did you install the extension they require, as explained in https://github.com/VirgilSecurity/virgil-cryptowrapper-php#additional-information?

Comment: Yes and code updated. I didn't go through Configure SDK as I'm trying to encrypt a string without having Virgil app key or so. Am I missing something?